# The Limit of The Sequence Given By a Recursive Relation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$a_{n+1} = a_n(2^n - 1)/2^n$ for all natural numbers $n$

and $a_1 = 1$.

I show that this sequence has a limit by using the monotone convergence theorem, yet I could not find what the limit is explicitly.

Can you find what the limit is? With a regirous proof.

Any kind of help, hint or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Strange, if $a_0$ exists, then $a_1=0$.  So $a_0$ can't exist.

Comment: "yet I could not find what the limit is explicitly. "  Why do you think you have to and why do you think you can.  Showing that a limit exist doesn't necessarily mean you have to find it.

Comment: I wanted to find the limit just for curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\qquad\qquad a_{n+1} & =a_n\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right) \\
& =a_{n-1}\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right) \\
& =a_{n-2}\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-2}}\right)\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

$$\text{etc.}$$

$$a_{n+1}=a_1\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_1\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)$$

$$\qquad =a_1\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)$$

$$=a_1\phi(1/2)=Qa_1\approx0.2887880950\times a_1$$

where $\phi(1/2)$ is [Euler's phi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) (please see link, as this is not the regular "Euler's phi function").

This is also the somewhat famously known as the $Q$ that appears in [Tree Searching (19)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TreeSearching.html).

So for $a_1=1$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\phi(1/2)=Q\approx0.2887880950$$

Comment: The phrase "Euler phi-function" is usually reserved for the number of positive integers relatively prime to and not exceeding the (positive integer) argument, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: @GerryMyerson I didn't know what to actually call it sadly.